# Solving merge conflict on git stash apply

Tags: git

I did a `git stash` on branch I am working on and checkout out to another branch. Now when I checked out to my previous branch and did a `git stash apply` it shows I have a conflict

```
Auto-merging projects/src/app/feature/some.service.ts
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in projects/src/app/feature/some.service.ts
```

I have resolved the conflict and tried the `git stash apply` but it still throws the same error. Tried resolving the conflict, `git add .` and `git stash apply`, still same error.

I saw many threads talking about resolving this but I am afraid I may loose all my changes. Pls help

Comment: at this point it says ```On branch feat-detailsscreen
nothing to commit, working tree clean```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you have fixed your conflicts and run `git add .`, you are done.

You don't need to apply an extra `git stash apply`.

---

If you want to inspect what is in your topmost stash, use :

```
# will show a summary of what files were touched :
git stash show

# will show the diff of what is stashed :
git stash show -p
```

If you want to list all the stuff you currently have in your stashes :

```
git stash list
```

If you want to inspect a specific stash :

```
git stash show [-p] stash@{xx}

# stash@{0} is the topmost stash,
# 'git stash show stash@{0}' is the same as 'git stash show'
```

You can also apply a specific stash :

```
git stash apply stash@{xx}
```

Comment: But I still do not see my previous changes that were stashed.

Comment: ```git stash show``` showing the file I resolved for the conflict. It is not showing all my stashed files

Comment: `git stash apply` will try to apply the *diff* of your files when you stashed them. Do you want to get the *full content* of the files when you stashed them ?

Comment: Yes. For example I have a file and I modified the file and added some more content to it. Now I stashed this file and wanted get the changes I made to file by applying ```git stash apply```. I have been using this command for while and never had issues how it works

Comment: Say your starting branch is `work1`, your second branch is `work2`, and the file to which you added content is `foo.ts`. You say you have added some content to `foo.ts` when working on `work1`, correct ? Did you by any chance *commit* these modifications to `work1` before stashing ?

Comment: Yes I made changes for a file in branch ```work1``` and did not commit.

Comment: Ok. If the modifications you expect do not show up in `git stash show -p`, check your `git stash list`.

Comment: Ok I see my changes are in ```git stash show stash@{1}```. How to get them into my branch

Comment: Thanks alot @LeGEC. git stash apply stash@{1} worked.

Comment: @LeGEC, so you can do `git stash drop` now?

Comment: @aerjman : just be careful about the index of the stash you are dropping : `git stash drop` is the same as `git stash drop stash@{0}`. You may want to run `git stash drop stash@{1}`, or `git stash drop stash@{xx}`. Do check `git stash list` to have a view of your current stash entries.

Comment: @aerjman : the `stash@{xx}` syntax also works with `git stash pop` : `git stash pop stash@{1}` will both apply, and if succesful drop the stash.